# Implementing some form of templating mechanism

Tags: feature-request, markdown

In [JavaScript answers using ES5 features: Warn or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not), user [GGG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176318/ggg) commented:

> It would be great if SO had wiki-like templates for things like this, so you could just do {{ES5}} and be done with it.

In the JavaScript community we have a situation where some people think we should warn people about browser compliance for every feature we use in answers.

Manually linking people to browser compliance charts for ES5, DOM, XHR and other w3c/whatwg standards is an annoying thing to do and is easy to automate.

Is there any possibility for implementing either a per user mechanism or a site wide mechanism for tags like {{ES5}} that would print some kind of generic browser compliance disclaimer?

[Example answer I made today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770547/c-sharp-class-to-js-class/8770704#8770704), in this particular case I felt like being nice and adding

> **Disclaimer:** example code uses ES5, deal with legacy browser engines in a sensible manner yourself.

Normally I would just not bother with this, however if we have any kind of really simple mechanism for injecting generic disclaimers it would be useful.

This could be applicable to other areas as well, for example Android version disclaimers or any other kind of answer where we should put disclaimers about undefined behaviour or known broken / old implementations of some form of standard.

Comment: Agree, it's really annoying to put MDN pages for `Array#forEach`, `Array#filter` etc when answering questions without jquery tag.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a userscript that inserts canned text snippets.

Comment: Yeah I just created a greasemonkey script for this ^^